# Передача данных между формами в С#

Tags: c#, winforms

Решил попробовать сделать программку, в которой значение передавалось бы между формами через сохранение в статическую переменную. Планировал счётчик передавать между формами, чтобы в каждой форме в `label` отображалось одно и то же значение.
Код программы:

```
/*Program.cs*/
namespace program14
{
static class Program
{
...................................................
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
public static class Counter
{
    public static int Count = 0;
}
}

/*Form1*/
namespace program14
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static int number = 0;
..................................................
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        number++;
        Counter.Count = number;
        label1.Text = Convert.ToString(Counter.Count);
    }
}
```

Ну, в общем-то, и всё. Жмём на кнопку - `number` увеличивается на единицу - в `label1` отображается единица. Проблема лишь в том, что единица не отображается. Значение из `number` не копируется в `Counter.Count`. Проверяя с помощью "Выполнить до текущей позиции", убедился в этом: значение не изменяется, как было 0, так и остаётся. Очевидно, вторую форму я и создавать не стал. Что я делаю не так? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Довольно странно выглядит, по-идее всё должно работать и значение должно присваиваться. Ты пробовал "чистить" проект и компилировать снова?

Comment: А может сделать Count не static?

Comment: @АлексейСаровский ну вот я попробовал, говорит, что для нестатического поля требуется ссылка на объект. А сделать я её не могу в этом случае.

Comment: @bravo4827 Я только что полностью новый проект создал, скопировав код. У меня всё работает. Может быть, что-то поломано в Designer классе формы? Попробуй удалить label, добавить новый и скопировать код в обработчик событий.

Comment: @Alex, да, попробовал почистить, не помогает :(

Comment: @Alex, к сожалению, даже в новом проекте не работает это...

Comment: @bravo4827 Как ты запускаешь программу?

Comment: Да как обычно запускал, через "Запуск", Debug. Но проблема решилась, правда, идиотским способом. Запустил VC15 на другом компьютере и скомпилировал там. На основном же, в MVC12, проблема так и осталась. Наверно, стоит перезагрузиться и там.